# How to Access data of current price of stocks in Pine Editor Tradingview using ticker id

Tags: python, editor, indicator, tradingview-api

i want to code indicator in my tradingview pine editor, for that, I need the current price of a stock or any other scrip to my coding keyword to do operations and generate new output on chart,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
src = input(close, title="Source")

price = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, src)

plot(price)
```

Here ticker id I used to display the current price on the chart

reference  [intradaygeeks](http://youtube.com/intradaygeeks) contact if need more help [twitter](https://twitter.com/intradaygeeks)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

> `currentPrice = security(syminfo.tickerid, "", ema(close, 1), barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off)`

You could probably use something other than ema(). If you're writing a strategy, make sure your call to strategy includes `calc_on_every_tick=true`.

> `strategy("DCA Bot", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)`